# Null Pointer Exception While Creating side bar navigation in android

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, navbar

I am trying to Create side bar navigation in android but there is one problem I am facing.I went through so many post on stackoverflow but it didn't solved my problem

I am following the tutorial exactly mentioned [here](https://medium.com/quick-code/android-navigation-drawer-e80f7fc2594f)

But when I a running my app I am getting error

```
   Process: com.example.deepak.myapplication, PID: 26704
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.deepak.myapplication/com.example.deepak.myapplication.Naviagtion}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2721)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2782)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1521)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6228)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference
    at com.example.deepak.myapplication.Naviagtion.onCreate(Naviagtion.java:29)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6871)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2674)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2782) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1521) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6228) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
```

I am using styles as mentioned

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

Also I am Extending  AppCompatActivity

So please help me and let me know where I am going wrong

Comment: please post full your theme define and your layout xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have not set ActionBar, put this line above

```
 setSupportActionBar(toolbar);  // <--- put this 
 ActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
```

Comment: I don't have any toolbar in my xml and where should I add toolbar in my xml

Comment: find toolbar id from xml file

Comment: I haven't used any toolbar in xml

Comment: you should remove this ActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true) if you are not using toolbar